# Is there a way to read from a continously updated file the new updates only in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream

I have a log file that is continuously updated and additional data are added. I am trying to read from this file specific lines which start with [rosout] and I want to show whatever data is added after the first time I read from the file.

What I did is the I created an array and I stated an if condition to add only the logs that I want and it worked, I also placed the watch method to execute my function whenever the file is updated. But am stuck when it comes to adding new logs only, I tried working with array.includes(the read line) before adding to the array but it didn't work.

```
fs.watch('filepath', (eventType, filename) => {
 var readline= require('readline');
 var stream= require('stream');
 var instream = fs.createReadStream('filepath');
 var outstream= new stream();
 var rl= readline.createInterface(instream,outstream);
 var errors=[];
var error=false;

rl.on('line', function(line){
error=line.includes("rosout")
if(error==true){
if(!errors.includes("line")){
 errors.push(line); 
console.log(errors.join("\r\n"));
}}
});
});
```

I expect the output to be log data that starts with rosout and which updates with the additional data only whenever the file is updated.

Comment: I found the dupetarget using [this search](/search?q=%5Bnodejs%5D+read+file+being+written+to). More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: `!errors.includes("line")` will search for the string `"line"` inside the array, not the actual value of the variable. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: I even used !errors.includes(line) to check if the value of the variable: line is in the array before adding it.